# What do IP adresses for eth0 and eth1 stand for?

Tags: virtual-machine, network-interface, ip

I `ssh`ed to my vagrant machine.

```
  System load:  0.13              Processes:           169
  Usage of /:   6.6% of 61.80GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 76%               IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.11
  Swap usage:   16%               IP address for eth1: 192.100.0.12
```

What is the difference between the two private IPs?

Comment: That only one of them is a "private" IP?

Comment: RFC 1918 defines, and IANA reserves the following blocks as private networks: `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255`, `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255`, and `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255`. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

Comment: @Christopher I see now. Is there any peril in using 192.100 for my Vagrant machine?

Comment: Of course there is peril in using a "public" internet address. (1) it belongs to *NetDocuments* in US (try whois 192.100.0.12), a private company, you have no (legal) right to use their IP's. (2) Using a public IP address exposes the interface to traffic from **anywhere** in the internet.

Comment: It would be much safer (and legit) to use another private IP space for Vagrant. Perhaps `10.1.x.x` or `172.16.x.x`. That way you never collide with outside networks.

Comment: And then you ... and this table appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two private IP's?

Each Ethernet interface must have a different IP. Usually closely related like 10.0.0.1 and 10.1.1.25, both private and in one single block of addresses. Sometimes in separate [1918 private ip blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) like 10.0.2.11 and 192.168.0.12.

But one of your IPs is **not** private, it is owned by a company:

```
$ whois 192.100.0.12
...
NetRange:       192.100.0.0 - 192.100.0.255
CIDR:           192.100.0.0/24
Comment:        NetVoyage (aka NetDocuments)

OrgName:        NetDocuments
OrgId:          NC-252
Address:        2500 W Executive Parkway
StateProv:      UT
Country:        US
```

And there are many (a lot) of other companies all over the world in the range 192.100.x.x:

```
$ whois 192.100.1.1
inetnum:        192.100.1.0 - 192.100.1.255
descr:          Computing Centre for Water Research
country:        ZA

organisation:   ORG-CCfW1-AFRINIC
org-name:       Computing Centre for Water Research
org-type:       LIR
```

In South Africa.

- You have no (legal) right to use any of those addresses.
- Using that address exposes that interface to traffic (possible attacks) from anywhere in the world.